# vb.net writeline expression not valid?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, expression, streamwriter

This expression is not valid: `sw.WriteLine("$destination=[Environment]::GetFolderPath("Startup")")`

I put a comma and $ symbol between ")") but it didn't work. Help Please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes:

```
sw.WriteLine("$destination=[Environment]::GetFolderPath(""Startup"")")
```

Comment: Glad to help.  Feel free to mark that as the answer if it is what you needed.